# Will my expoxy eventually cure below 40 degrees?

Tags: concrete, epoxy

I'm in the northeast and on Sunday afternoon (today is Thursday) I installed a post in my driveway with Quikrete High Strength Anchoring Epoxy. It was 60˚ F. Then over the next couple hours the temperature dropped to below 40˚ F and stayed there, and it isn't forecast to go above 40˚ F for at least the next 10 days. Plus there's a snowstorm coming.

I did not know this at the time, but now I am reading that epoxies don't cure below 40˚ F. Am I completely screwed? Should I go out with a hair dryer or something? Can I just let it sit for weeks until the temp climbs back up? It's already been 4 days between 20-40˚ F.

I'm afraid to seriously test the post, but with a little pressure it does feel like it wiggles more than I expect it to (which would be none at all).

Thanks for any advice.

JMT

ETA: pics

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming it hasn't frozen during its liquid state you can you can aim a hair dryer at it for a few hours. How important is this post? You can just leave it or remove it and try again in the spring.

Comment: The post is part of a flood barrier system (the house flooded during Ida). So it's pretty important, but probably not until next spring. It could have waited -- I just had no idea the temp would affect it this much.

Comment: Curing is always a fickle beast. Given that the instructions say "Adhesive is fully cured and achieves best strength in 24 hours at 77 °F" and 5 days later it still wiggles tells me you'll need a do-over in the spring. However, you provide no pictures you if you're wiggling the top of a 6 foot post then of course you're going to feel wiggle due to simple lever advantage.

Comment: I'd ask the company. Their tech spec doesn't mention it. The potential answers are "it will cure once it's warmed up" [like silicone] or "No, sorry, you're screwed." [like portland cement]. Im not sure anyone else can guess at that.

Comment: Added pics. It is a very slight wiggle, but I'm afraid to push it hard to find out if it'll move more. I just put a space heater on it, and my temp sensor says it's 75˚ at least there above the ground. I'll just see what happens. Thanks to you both for your help.

Comment: I think you are pretty much in the "screwed" side of the situation. I worked with refinery/chem plant coatings, many were epoxy. Many millions of dollars worth of paint jobs were redone because " we didn't think it would get that cold at night" ( before the epoxy cured).

Comment: Is that post surface epoxied to the concrete?

Comment: No. I didn't take pics of the entire process, but the post screws into a base so that it can be installed/removed as needed. The base is flush with the driveway, and epoxied into a ~5" deep hole. The driveway is slightly graded in that spot, so the shims are there to keep the post vertical.

Comment: So what wiggles, the post or the base? The post has mechanical leverage so wiggling is expected. If the base wiggles then that's a problem.

Comment: If you look in the pic, you can see (barely) a small plastic disc underneath the pole. Looks like a white CD. That disc is protecting the pole from the epoxy, but it's also preventing me from seeing the base until I remove both pole and disc. 1/

Comment: That said, I checked it out just now and I feel a bit more optimistic. I put a space heater on it about 5-6 hours ago, and when I tested it I was able to tighten the screw a tiny bit, but no more, meaning the base is not spinning freely in the epoxy. So that's a good sign. Plus, after I tightened it it wiggles less (though still some), and finally I pushed a bit harder on it and despite the wiggle, it holds fast. 2/

Comment: So I covered it with a tarp to keep the snow off it tonight. Once it's safe, tomorrow or the day after, I'll put the heater back on it again for a few hours, and then when I think there's nothing left to try, I'll take the pole out and see where I am. Thanks again to everyone who replied. I'll report back on the results for anyone searching this in the future. 3/3

Comment: Don't move it until you are certain it has cured.  Otherwise you'll just break the bonds that are forming.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't yet. At Tetsujin's suggestion I emailed Quikrete, and they replied today: "The anchoring epoxy will continue to cure at the colder temperatures, but it will delay the curing process. It will just take longer to achieve strengths." Less specific than I would like, but very encouraging. I will put the heater on it again tomorrow for a few hours and I hope that will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that I was worried about nothing.  At Tetsujin's suggestion I emailed Quikrete, and they replied: "The anchoring epoxy will continue to cure at the colder temperatures, but it will delay the curing process. It will just take longer to achieve strengths."

So after about 5 days of below 40 temps, I took it apart and discovered that it's solid as a rock. It's ugly, but I couldn't move it if I tried. Unfortunately, it seems that a lot of the epoxy escaped underneath the driveway, leaving a 1-2" trench around the base on one side. I'll fill that with either more epoxy or a sealant of some type to keep the water out.

Thanks to everyone who replied for your suggestions!

JMT

[image]

[image]